# How to hang heavy mirror

Tags: drywall

I need to hang a pretty heavy mirror over 50lbs but I do not have a stud. The wall is drywall. I wanted to use [Hillman 122310 Brass Conventional Picture Hangers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BQN94W), but the instructions on the back say the 100lb weight support is only if you hit a stud.

Can someone tell me what works well for a heavy mirror that does not have a wire on the back of it. It basically has two circles on the back framed so that a high or screw can be placed into it.

Do I need a stud 100% or can I go right to drywall only?

Comment: Why don’t you have any studs in the wall? Or do you mean you just have not looked for them or found them?

Comment: I dont have a stud in this location or the location is quite odd. Is there a solution with drywall only?

Comment: So, no studs on an 8 by 4 sheet of drywall or is there a stud some distance away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hillman makes a "no stud" picture/mirror hanger that supposed to be good for 200 lbs for 1/2" or 5/8" drywall. (see below). I've used them for very heavy mirrors when studs were not available at the exact location I needed to hang them. You'd need two, one for each "circle" on the frame.

[image]

Comment: Wow I have used another brand but had no idea they were rated for that much weight. The tiny nails are easy to patch+

Comment: Jack can you link me?

Comment: @JonH https://www.amazon.com/Hillman-122370-Drywall-Picture-Hanger/dp/B000BQS2LM/ref=asc_df_B000BQS2LM/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=198055620944&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=5562647703179840717&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9011856&hvtargid=aud-801738734305:pla-319675781963&psc=1

Answer (score 1):

When I put up a heavy mirror I do not "hang" it, I support the bottom. Then if the mirror has holes you can use regular drywall anchors ( plastic liners in small holes) at the top to keep it from tipping away from the wall. If no holes use molding at the top.  The bottom support can be any wood molding or aluminum or steel angle ;these are supported at every stud for the length of the mirror. I presume a "heavy" mirror is at least 32 " wide/ three studs.  I see that is also what the carpenters did in my house; One large mirror sits on top of a sink backslash. The others sit on the same wood molding as around the doors and the molding is continued around the sides and top.